# jQuery clone jQueryUI slider weird behaviour

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-slider

On a page, when a user fills in a searchbox, I add a search result div with rows cloned (withDataAndEvents = true) with jQuery. Some of these rows contain form elements and some a jQuery UI slider. Events to these elements are bound with the data-bind feature of knockoutJS. Event handlers on regular form elements work fine, but not for the jQuery UI slider. When dragging the handles, it jumps back to the original row.

Some code:

```
$(divselector).each(function (i, div) {
     if (arrPropertyGuids.indexOf($(div).attr("data-propertyguid")) == -1) {
         $("#propertiesSearchPanel").append($(div).clone(true).show());
     }
 });
```

I loop through some divs (rows) and add them one by one to the result panel, by cloning them (also tried deep cloning with no difference). Some divs are hidden in the source so I need to call .show().

What I did try:

- Tried to re-initiliaze the sliders. But no different behaviour detected.
- Tried to destroy and initialize the sliders after cloning, but this gives an error:

> cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

```
 $(".range-slider").slider("destroy");
```

So, it seems to me that in one way or another, the cloned slider is not a "real" jQuery UI slider, but still linked to original elements.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have one working solution, but not an ideal one. So I'm leaving this question open in case someone might have a better answer.

I simply deleted all sliders and than re-added the div tags. After that, I reapplied the jQuery UI slider init functions.

```
 $("#propertiesSearchPanel").find(".range-slider").remove();
        $("#propertiesSearchPanel .range-box").each(function (i, tb) {
           $(tb).next("label").after('<div class="range-slider"></div>');
        }
 });
 sliders($("#propertiesSearchPanel")); //init functions for sliders
```